# Как регулярным выражением вырезать из списка

Tags: python, синтаксис

Дан список - 17 элементов. В каждом элементе как бы свой список, но это строка.

Как из каждого элемента регулярным выражением вырезать текст ,который стоит по счету во вторых кавычках?

Должен сформироваться второй список . 
Пример списка:

```
[Вытяжка для настенного монтажа, Компактная посудомоечная машина, Газовая варочная панель, ....  ]
```

первый элемент в списке вот такая строка:

```
["N 70","Вытяжка для настенного монтажа","","60 cm","нержавеющая сталь","D65BCP2N0"
```

Список

```
lst = ['["N 70","Вытяжка для настенного монтажа","","60 cm","нержавеющая сталь","D65BCP2N0"', '["Serie | 2","Компактная посудомоечная машина","","55 cm","Белый","SKS41E11RUB"', '["Serie | 4","Газовая варочная панель","","60 cm","Pearl white","PGP6B1B60R"', '["","Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., коричневый орех","","","","00649058"', '["","Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., жёлтый лайм","","","","00649057"', '["","Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., мятный голубой","","","","00649056"', '["","Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., клубничный красный","","","","00649055"', '["","Кольцо для WOK-конфорки","","","","00647832"', '["","Кольцо для WOK-конфорки","","","","00647535"', '["","Любителям итальянской кухни: набор PastaPassion, для MUM8.., MUMX..","","","","00576586"', '["","Защитный кожух Textile Protect для TDS16.., TDS20.., TDS22.., TDS35..,","TDS37.., TDS38.., TDS45..","","","00571510"', '["","Телескопические направляющие для 3 уровней, комплект","","","","00475131"', '["","Мясорубка + адаптер для кухонного комбайна, для MUM8.., MUMXL..","","","","00464423"', '["","Насадка-терка для сыра / шоколада, для MUM8..","","","","00463718"', '["","Насадка для приготовления спагетти, для MUM8.., MUMXL..","","","","00463688"', '["","Декоративная планка; цвет \\"сталь\\"","","","","00299984"', '["","Комплект для установки компактных посудомоечных машин","","","","00207709"']
```

Напишите пожалуйста готовое решение,которое можно вставить в редактор и запустить.

Comment: А почему в этом списке первым элементом строка (в апострофах), а в ней список, из которого вы и хотите вытащить данные?

Comment: Это и есть первый элемент списка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше, конечно, сразу правильно форматировать исходный список там, где он берется, но можно и так:

```
res = []

for el in lst:
    res.append(el.split(",")[1].replace('"',''))
```

Comment: Спасиб. Работает. Только хорошо бы еще кавычки в каждом элементе нового списка обрезать.

Comment: обрезал. (6 символов)

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: все. Разобрался. Ответы оцениваю.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать функцию `ast.literal_eval`, но нужно будет добавить закрывающую скобку в конце каждой строки:

```
import ast

lst = ['["N 70","Вытяжка для настенного монтажа","","60 cm","нержавеющая сталь","D65BCP2N0"', '["Serie | 2","Компактная посудомоечная машина","","55 cm","Белый","SKS41E11RUB"', '["Serie | 4","Газовая варочная панель","","60 cm","Pearl white","PGP6B1B60R"', '["","Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., коричневый орех","","","","00649058"', '["","Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., жёлтый лайм","","","","00649057"', '["","Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., мятный голубой","","","","00649056"', '["","Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., клубничный красный","","","","00649055"', '["","Кольцо для WOK-конфорки","","","","00647832"', '["","Кольцо для WOK-конфорки","","","","00647535"', '["","Любителям итальянской кухни: набор PastaPassion, для MUM8.., MUMX..","","","","00576586"', '["","Защитный кожух Textile Protect для TDS16.., TDS20.., TDS22.., TDS35..,","TDS37.., TDS38.., TDS45..","","","00571510"', '["","Телескопические направляющие для 3 уровней, комплект","","","","00475131"', '["","Мясорубка + адаптер для кухонного комбайна, для MUM8.., MUMXL..","","","","00464423"', '["","Насадка-терка для сыра / шоколада, для MUM8..","","","","00463718"', '["","Насадка для приготовления спагетти, для MUM8.., MUMXL..","","","","00463688"', '["","Декоративная планка; цвет \\"сталь\\"","","","","00299984"', '["","Комплект для установки компактных посудомоечных машин","","","","00207709"']

for item in lst:
    print(ast.literal_eval(item+']'))
```

Вывод:

```
['N 70', 'Вытяжка для настенного монтажа', '', '60 cm', 'нержавеющая сталь', 'D65BCP2N0']
['Serie | 2', 'Компактная посудомоечная машина', '', '55 cm', 'Белый', 'SKS41E11RUB']
['Serie | 4', 'Газовая варочная панель', '', '60 cm', 'Pearl white', 'PGP6B1B60R']
['', 'Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., коричневый орех', '', '', '', '00649058']
['', 'Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., жёлтый лайм', '', '', '', '00649057']
['', 'Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., мятный голубой', '', '', '', '00649056']
['', 'Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., клубничный красный', '', '', '', '00649055']
['', 'Кольцо для WOK-конфорки', '', '', '', '00647832']
['', 'Кольцо для WOK-конфорки', '', '', '', '00647535']
['', 'Любителям итальянской кухни: набор PastaPassion, для MUM8.., MUMX..', '', '', '', '00576586']
['', 'Защитный кожух Textile Protect для TDS16.., TDS20.., TDS22.., TDS35..,', 'TDS37.., TDS38.., TDS45..', '', '', '00571510']
['', 'Телескопические направляющие для 3 уровней, комплект', '', '', '', '00475131']
['', 'Мясорубка + адаптер для кухонного комбайна, для MUM8.., MUMXL..', '', '', '', '00464423']
['', 'Насадка-терка для сыра / шоколада, для MUM8..', '', '', '', '00463718']
['', 'Насадка для приготовления спагетти, для MUM8.., MUMXL..', '', '', '', '00463688']
['', 'Декоративная планка; цвет "сталь"', '', '', '', '00299984']
['', 'Комплект для установки компактных посудомоечных машин', '', '', '', '00207709']
```

Или через `json.loads`:

```
import json

for item in lst:
    print(json.loads(item+']'))
```

Результат будет тот же.

Comment: как будет выглядеть код,если убрать все  двойные кавычки из списка и запятые из каждого элемента в списке, но так что бы те слова, которые заключены в двойные кавычки не стояли вплотную.

Comment: @Webos, никак. Ответ писался именно под пример данных из вопроса.

Comment: Ок. Я уже разобрался.