# Как из списка вырезать весь текст и записать в новый список?

Tags: python, синтаксис

Как из списка вырезать весь текст и записать в новый список?
1.С помощью регулярного выражения.
2.С помощью другого метода.

Причем что бы отдельные слова не сливались и были разделенные пробелом.

Список

```
['["N 70","Вытяжка для настенного монтажа","","60 cm","нержавеющая
 сталь","D65BCP2N0"', '["Serie | 2","Компактная посудомоечная
 машина","","55 cm","Белый","SKS41E11RUB"', '["Serie | 4","Газовая
 варочная панель","","60 cm","Pearl white","PGP6B1B60R"',
 '["","Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., коричневый
 орех","","","","00649058"', '["","Комплект для смены цвета, для
 Tassimo TAS20.., жёлтый лайм","","","","00649057"', '["","Комплект для
 смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20.., мятный
 голубой","","","","00649056"', '["","Комплект для смены цвета, для
 Tassimo TAS20.., клубничный красный","","","","00649055"',
 '["","Кольцо для WOK-конфорки","","","","00647832"', '["","Кольцо для
 WOK-конфорки","","","","00647535"', '["","Любителям итальянской кухни:
 набор PastaPassion, для MUM8.., MUMX..","","","","00576586"',
 '["","Защитный кожух Textile Protect для TDS16.., TDS20.., TDS22..,
 TDS35..,","TDS37.., TDS38.., TDS45..","","","00571510"',
 '["","Телескопические направляющие для 3 уровней,
 комплект","","","","00475131"', '["","Мясорубка + адаптер для
 кухонного комбайна, для MUM8.., MUMXL..","","","","00464423"',
 '["","Насадка-терка для сыра / шоколада, для
 MUM8..","","","","00463718"', '["","Насадка для приготовления
 спагетти, для MUM8.., MUMXL..","","","","00463688"',
 '["","Декоративная планка; цвет \\"сталь\\"","","","","00299984"',
 '["","Комплект для установки компактных посудомоечных
 машин","","","","00207709"']
```

Должен быть список:

```
 [N 70 Вытяжка для настенного монтажа 60 cm нержавеющая сталь D65BCP2N0
 , Serie | 2 Компактная посудомоечная машина 55 cm Белый SKS41E11RUB ,
 Serie | 4 Газовая варочная панель 60 cm Pearl white PGP6B1B60R ,  ...
 ]
```

Код для получения начального списка. 
Список берется из спарсенной страницы в части , в которой данные формируются JavaScrip.

Вырезаю все данные после слова "headers"

```
#срезы с использование регулярных выражений
def find_segments(text, start, end):
    pattern = re.escape(start) + r'(.*?)' + re.escape(end)
    return re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.DOTALL)
f = open('srez.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') # открывает файл для записи
srez = find_segments(str(items), '"headers":', ']') # создает списко из срезов
f.write(str(srez))  # запись в файл данных srez.txt
f.close()
```

Вот такая строчка в спарсенной странице  ищется и вырезается  до символа ]

`"headers":["","Комплект для смены цвета, для Tassimo TAS20..,
 коричневый орех","","","","00649058"],`

Comment: У меня уже дежавю с этим списком :) Непонятно, что вы хотите сделать с этим, добавьте в вопрос ожидаемый результат. **Кст,** ответы нужно оценивать и те, что помогли отмечать (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), иначе вам могут перестать помогать. Например, в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1133220/201445 есть хорошие ответы, решающие проблему в вопросе.

Comment: Вы пока не оценили принятием **ни один** ваш вопрос. Не ожидайте дальнейшей помощи, пока вы это не сделаете, по крайней мере от меня.

Comment: а как оценивать? Когда нажимаю что бы оценить,то выходит что надо через какой-то сервис входить.

Comment: См. [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: добавил в вопрос пример результата

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, откуда вы вы вообще берете таки списки (списки со строками, в которых лежат другие списки).

Comment: добавил откуда берется такой список

Comment: `добавил откуда берется такой список` - это кусок данных в формате [json](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). С json лучше работать с помощью модуля json.

Comment: пробовал работать с json. Выдается постоянно ошибка. Поэтому применил регулярные выражения.

Comment: @Webos, "пробовал работать с json. Выдается постоянно ошибка." - нужно разбираться с ошибкой, а не городить костыли.

Comment: Перестаньте создавать велосипеды. Вы не осилите распарсить сырой json. Используйте модуль json, как советовал insolar. Начните читать документацию и/или гуглить. Не умеете в английский, гуглите по-русски. Уже давно есть нормальные переводы/адаптации питоновской документации на стандартную библиотеку

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение, которое мне подходит

```
# вырез из списка только текста 
res = [] # создание нового списка
lst = srez 
for el in lst:
    res.append(el.split(",")[0].replace('"','') +" "+ el.split(",")[1].replace('"','') +" "+ el.split(",")[2].replace('"','')+" "+ el.split(",")[3].replace('"','')+" "+ el.split(",")[4].replace('"','')+" "+ el.split(",")[5].replace('"','') )
```